# PhantomJSDriver.getCurrentUrl() return about:blank

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Hello i'm using phantomJS and selenuim to get some information from site.

the version that i use :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to init driver i use :

```
 File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack();
    // Create the driver
    DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());
    dcaps.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                    "Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
    );
    dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ssl-protocol=TLSv1"});
    dcaps.setBrowserName(BrowserType.FIREFOX_CHROME);
    dcaps.setPlatform(Platform.UNIX);
    dcaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps);
    driver.setLogLevel(Level.ALL);
```

when i want to get to any site i get undefined result:

```
driver.get(url1);
System.out.println("Browsing URL page Accueil : " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

i get in console Browsing URL page Accueil : about:blank

Any help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to http://www.markbetz.net/2014/11/10/phantomjs-aboutblank-and-ssl-protocol/comment-page-1/

the solution is to add Capability "--ssl-protocol=any"